# Steiner-like systems on $\omega$

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, steiner-triple-system

Let $S(\omega)$ denote the collection of "sparse" infinite subsets of $\omega$, that is, $X\subseteq \omega$ is a member of $S(\omega)$ if and only if both $X$ and $\omega\setminus X$ are infinite.

Is there ${\cal S}\subseteq S(\omega)$ such that for all $a\neq b \in \omega$ we have $|\{s\in {\cal S}: \{a,b\} \subseteq s\}| = 1$?

Comment: I assume you mean $\{a,b\}\subseteq s$, since both $\{a,b\}$ and $s$ are subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: Right @AndreasBlass - sorry for the notational error -> will correct this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, let $K$ be any countably infinite field and let $P$ be the projective plane (or a higher-dimensional projective space)  over $K$. Let $S'$ be the set of lines in $P$ (where a line is regarded as a set of points), and transport the family $S'$ of subsets of $P$ to a family $S$ of subsets of $\omega$ via your favorite enumeration of $P$.

Comment: Affine plane would work just as well, right?

Comment: @bof Yes. (I just happen to like projective geometry.)